# Value of an if statement is not returning to the context of the parent function the view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, view

This is the view I want to use `obj3` in the context of the function

```
def inec_news_view(request):

    title = 'LGA Results'
    data1 = Lga.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_item = request.POST.get('item_id')
        obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=Subquery(Unit.objects.values('uniqueid').filter(lga_id=obj1)))
    context = {'title': title, 'data1': data1, 'resobj': obj3}
    return render(request, "inecnews.html", context)
```

Comment: `obj3` is a local variable. If it needs to be used in another function, you need to make it global.

Comment: what error are you getting? You need to define `obj3` for `GET` method if you are using it because this variable currenty is undefined without calling `POST`, while you are putting it into context in any case.

Comment: It looks like if you make a GET request, it will error, since then `obj3` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks guys I figure out the issue

Comment: @Barmar please don't suggest using globals, and specially NOT in a wsgi program. As a general rule, if you want to make a local variable accessible outside a function, the proper way is to return it from the function (or encapsulate it as part of an object or closure), and given wsgi's execution model, globals in a wsgi app should NEVER been used for sharing global state.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I would have suggested returning it, but this function is being called by the framework so you can't change the return value.

Comment: @Barmar of course you can - just use a TemplateResponse, and you'll have full access to the context. And if you have more than one function needing to execute the same code, nothing prevents you from extracting this into it's own function and call it where needed. In all cases, mutable globals are evil in general and can NOT be used to maintain mutable shared state in a multiprocess setup. But anyway: if you read the question, it's actually not about the function's return value but about passing some object to the template's context.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I answered it

```
    def inec_news_view(request): # *args, **kwargs
        title = 'LGA Results'
        data1 = Lga.objects.all()
        context = {'title': title, 'data1': data1}

        if request.method == 'POST':
            selected_item = request.POST.get('item_id')
            obj = Lga.objects.get(lga_id=selected_item)
            obj1 = obj.lga_id
            obj3 = Pu_results.objects.filter(polling_unit_uniqueid__in=Subquery(Unit.objects.values('uniqueid').filter(lga_id=obj1)))


            context = {'title': title, 'data1': data1, 'resobj': obj3}
        return render(request, "inecnews.html", context)
```